# SKEmitterNode: altering birth rate on update not adding more particles

Tags: sprite-kit, skemitternode

I have an SKEmitterNode on my scene,  when I increase the particles on update, the amount of particles being shown are not increasing.  I am not sure what step I am missing.

The code is really simple:

Create any kind of default particle from Xcode.

Set birthrate to 1, max to 0
Everything else doesn't really matter.

On GameScene update:

```
func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
    //whatever it takes to get the particle from the scene
    let particles = childNodeWithName("particles") as? SKEmitter

    particles!.particleBirthRate = particles!.particleBirthRate + 1;
}
```

Note: When doing a print,  the birth rate does increase, so I know it is not using a copy

Comment: By throwing it onto the scene from sprite kit editor

Comment: I use a SKEmitter particles increments with NSTimer, so I'm sure that the particles increases with the same period. It works

Comment: I've use a SKReferenceNode, and inside it a reference of a particles.sks file.

Comment: I am definitely not getting the results I want,  in fact, just by setting the birthrate = 1,  I am getting a different result then expected (it keeps a constant set of particles on screen, but not 1, a ton)

Comment: using an SKReference gets me the same effect  (BTW you shouldn't be using NSTimer with Sprite Kit,  if the timing of the scene changes or pauses, NSTimer does not change or pause with it)

Comment: birthrate = 1 it create one particle every second. If you want only one particles you must set max particle to 1. After change particleBirthRate + 1 and max +1 and call resetSimulation(). If I understand what effect do you want.

Comment: max is  set to 0, so that means infinite particles, if I set a max, then it no longer repeats and dies after max particles.  calling resetSimulation would not work because it resets the simulation, so nothing would happen because I am constantly resetting it on update

Comment: changing the birthrate seems to reset the number of particles in the emitter, thus causing the undesired effect

Comment: May be because is a let instead of var?

Comment: ... no let is being used correctly,  I am not changing the variable to a different instance of an emitter

Comment: i submitted a bug to apple,  the birthrate should not be resetting the emitting timer/ or firing a particle immediately